# Continuous , strictly monotone function on real line preserving subgroups

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an injective continuous function such that for every subgroup $G$ of $(\mathbb R, +)$ , $f(G)$ is also a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ . Then how to show that for some $c\in \mathbb R$ , $f(x)=cx , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ? Since $f$ is continuous, it is enough to show that $f$ is additive , and then again by continuity , it is enough to show that for some dense subsets $A,B$ of real line , $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) , \forall a \in A , b\in B$ . But I am unable to show any of these . I know that continuous and injectivity implies $f$ is strictly monotone , but I am not sure whether that's useful or not.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Every subgroup of $\mathbb R$ that has a minimum positive element $r$ is equal to $r\mathbb Z$. To see this, observe that any other element $r'$ must be a multiple of $r$ by a Euclid's algorithm-style argument: $r'-\lfloor r'/r\rfloor r$ lies in $[0,r)$, so must be $0$.

Define $c=f(1)$. For each $n\neq 0$, since $f$ is strictly monotone and sends $0$ to $0$ (the unique $1$-element subgroup), $|f(1/n)|$ must be the minimum positive element of $f(\frac{1}{n}\mathbb Z)$. By induction we get $f(m/n)=m f(1/n)=mc/n$ for all integers $m$, and this also holds for all non-zero $n$, so by continuity $f(x)=cx$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Supposing $f$ is increasing , you can say $f((1/n)\mathbb Z)=f(1/n)\mathbb Z$ , but from there you can't really directly say $f(m/n)=mf(1/n)$ ...

Comment: @misao: The argument I had in mind is that by induction you can prove that the $m$'th positive element of $f((1/n)\mathbb Z)$ is $m$ times the minimum positive element. This gives $f(m/n)=mf(1/n)$ for either all positive integer $m$ or all negative integer $m$, and by a symmetric argument, for all integer $m$.